# how to call javascript function from c++ in cocos2d-x

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x

In my cocos2d-x js project, I bind c++ functions to js using cxx-generator, in this way, I create an ios alertView and show it form my js code, but when user press OK button, I can pass the event to js now, I tried and googled all the 2 days, but I can not do it, if anyone knows what the solution is, please help me, thanks very very much!

Comment: You should REALLY add more code into your question, theres nothing to answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You didn't provide any code, so it's hard to give you specific help, but something like this should provide some direction:

Poo.h

```
class JSObject;
class Poo : cocos2d::CCNode {
  public:
    static void hello(JSObject *target, std::string selector);
}
```

Poo.cpp

```
Poo::hello(JSObject *target, std::string selector) {
    if (target) {
        js_proxy_t * p;
        JS_GET_PROXY(p, target);
        if (!p) {
            return;
        }

        jsval retval;
        jsval dataVal = std_string_to_jsval(ScriptingCore::getInstance()->getGlobalContext(), "Hello World");

        ScriptingCore::getInstance()->executeFunctionWithOwner(OBJECT_TO_JSVAL(p->obj), selector.c_str(), 1, &dataVal, &retval);
    }
}
```

Then, in your JS file:

```
var Demo = cc.Node.extend({
  ctor: function() {
    this._super();
    // The usual init stuff
    Poo.hello(this, "myCallback");
  },

  myCallback: function(msg) {
    cc.log("I got a message back from C++: " + msg);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please invoke this._super(); in ctor method.

```
ctor: function()
{
    this._super();
    // The usual init stuff
    Poo.hello(this, "myCallback");
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow!  You might want to add a bit more of an  explanation of what this does, so that it's more relevant to other people and is clear what it does.

Answer (score 0):

This answer does not work anymore with latest Cocos2dx versions. 3.12 does not have "JS_GET_PROXY"...

I spent several days trying to figure out how to fire a call to a JS function from C++, with no avail. So at the end of the day I found a hacky way to send and receive messages between the two, by creating custom cc.nodes and using already implemented getter and setter functions to send information in their fields.

Comment: Hi @maja, can you please share code.. want to know how to manage call javascript function from cocos2dx???