# How to call javascript function and pass value from c++ in Cocos2d-X/Cocos2d-JS with cocos creator

Tags: javascript, c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js, cocoscreator

I want to call my javascript function from my Cocos2d-X cpp file and want to pass data from cpp class to javascript file.
I tried and google it, but the solution i found was old and not found in current version of Cocos2dx/ Cocos creator. If anyone knows what the solution is, please help me, thanks very very much!

Already tried this [how to call javascript function from c++ in cocos2d-x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15543840/how-to-call-javascript-function-from-c-in-cocos2d-x)
and https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-call-js-functions-in-c-class/6243/3 But these solutions are old.

Comment: I have the same issue is any one have answer please share the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution. Below link solved my problem :- 
https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/evalstring-function-is-missing-js-function-call-from-objective-c/47530